# Spring Boot Views are not found when run from a directory containing a space

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm having an issue where my Spring Boot service with embedded Tomcat will serve jsps properly if run from a directory such as C:\example but the jsp files  are not found if I run it from C:\space example. The two jars are the same, just copied to different directories. I'm testing on Windows 10 with Spring boot 1.5.9, spring framework 5.0.3, and embedded tomcat (and jasper) 8.5.24. The jsps are stored in Meta-INF/resources.

It needs to be able to be run from Program Files(x86) which is why I need the space to work.

Comment: how do you run it?

Comment: Looks like we are back to thinking it's just a jsp issue. We are currently wrapping it up with exe4j and running it as an executable. We tried commenting out the InternalViewResolver and it downloaded the jsp, but did not actually convert our jsp tags or show it as a page.